# Why would CouldNotOpenProcess Exception - Could not open process: "PID of Process" in python appear?

Tags: python

I am trying to open a process and it's dll; but it tells me it could not open the process, and I am not sure why.

```py
import pymem
from pymem import Pymem

class MP:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.process = Pymem("gta_sa.exe")
        self.module = pymem.process.module_from_name(
            self.process.process_handle, "samp.dll"
        ).lpBaseOfDll

    def close(self) -> None:
        self.process.close_process() 

amp = MP()
```

Error:

> Could not open process: "PID of Process"

Comment: Can you include the full error message in your post?

Comment: Is gta_sa.exe running when you start your program?  If it's not running, it won't be found.

You could try writing a loop that will catch the exception, then wait some number of seconds and retry, up to a max number of retries before exiting.

Comment: Exception has occurred: CouldNotOpenProcess
Could not open process: (and here is the pid of the game)   thats the error, i tried a few months ago but using another method and it worked (not with Pymem), gta_sa.exe is running, else it would give me ProcessNotFound if i am not wrong

Comment: did you run your script as Administrator?

Comment: yep. thanks everyting is perfect now

Answer (score 1):

run your script as Administrator